Allow fullcalendar events to span over multiple days buisness hours
I'm trying to use fullcalendar to create a planning application for organising jobs. I am using React. I have created some draggable events to plot on the calendar with specific durations. One of the issues I'm coming across is that when an event goes outside of the working week I would like it to wrap around to start from the next working day.
The behaviour seems to either be to completely restrict events to have to end on that day using the or the event will continue outside of working hours and the timings will be off. I have set the minSlot and maxSlot and created custom working hours as you can see from the following code. Is there anyway to get the result I'm looking for? Below is the code I am using to create draggable events and the settings for the calendar.
Draggable
const containerEl = document.querySelector("#events");

let draggable = new Draggable(containerEl, {
    itemSelector: ".event",
    eventData: (eventEl) => {
        return {
            id: eventEl.innerText,
            title: eventEl.innerText,
            duration: eventEl.getAttribute('eventduration'),
            backgroundColor: eventEl.getAttribute('eventcolor'),
            borderColor: eventEl.getAttribute('eventcolor'),
            textColor: eventEl.getAttribute('eventtextcolor')
        };
    }
});

Events (Jobs)
      <ul id="events" className="d-flex flex-wrap">
                {
                    data.map(item => {
                        if(item.duration > 0) {
                            let textClass = 'text-white';

                            if(item.textColor === '#000') {
                                textClass = 'text-dark';
                            }

                            return (
                                <li className={"event badge bg-" + item.status + " " + textClass + " d-block mb-2 me-2"} eventtextcolor={item.textColor} eventcolor={item.backgroundColor} eventduration={new Date(item.duration * 1000).toISOString().substring(11, 16)}>{item.title}</li>
                            )   
                        }
                    })
                }
            </ul>

Calendar Settings
            <FullCalendar
                plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
                initialView="timeGridWeek"
                editable
                slotMinTime={"06:00"}
                slotMaxTime={"19:00"}
                eventDurationEditable={false}
                droppable
                businessHours={{
                    daysOfWeek: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                    startTime: '08:00',
                    endTime: '17:00',
                }}
                slotDuration={'00:10:00'}
                allDaySlot={false}
            />

I have tried using the nextDayThreshold to force the jobs to start at a specific time however I could not get the behaviour I would like with this. I would have expected the slotMinTime to continue duration straight from the slotMaxTime so the entire duration of the event is inside of the calendar and not hidden in the hours no one can see.

I don't believe this is currently possible, no. https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features

Thanks, I did originally think I may be able to create this myself on the event drop and create events but it feels like it'd be a bodge and probably difficult to maintain when dragging events around. I'll create a feature request as for planning jobs I'm surprised there's not one already.
